Git still taking HUGE amount of time to push after removing multiple files
I have a git repo which I was updating locally, but did not push to remote for a few months. But now I had to push it to remote and it was failing because there were a lot of files. The files were scattered across the repo, so it was impossible to have an easy way(like a wild card or git rm a directory).
So I created a temp/ folder and i gitignored it. Then moved all those files from across the repo to git.
This did not seem to have reduced the number of files being moved to the remote. So I ran
git rm -r --cached temp/
This also did not reduce all the files. So what do I do now to remove those hundreds of files that were moved to temp from all over the repo?
EDIT:
Here is the complete error:
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 556, done.
Counting objects: 100% (556/556), done.
Delta compression using up to 10 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (530/530), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 3 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

EDIT:
After doing
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
push happens, but terminates with this error:
remote: warning: File scripts/AllOrders_/allrprt316741019304.json is 51.48 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File scripts/AllOrdOld/allrprt313056019278.json is 52.88 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File scripts/AllOrders/allrprt317646019310.json is 50.66 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File scripts/AllOrders_/allrprt314301019286.json is 55.68 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File scripts/AllOrders/allrprt317647019310.json is 58.54 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File scripts/AllOrders_/allrprt314303019286.json is 51.27 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 4c1f4abe5802f0f9eb25c693f97555fc1e9e4da8ea5bb7899bc8e083ff67c625
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_312737019277.json is 157.16 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_312709019277.json is 145.15 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_312768019277.json is 152.36 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_342138019477.json is 236.58 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_308757019254.json is 176.23 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_306823019239.json is 184.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_304564019226.json is 171.34 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements_old/settlement_299482019197.json is 107.77 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File scripts/settlements/settlement_310904019267.json is 158.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

I had moved these files to temp/ folder which is git ignored (note that there are many other files in log, i am just sharing a part of it). So my initial guess was correct. I want to remove these files from tracking and when i do a git rm (with or without --cached option), I get refspec path not found error.

This is an XY problem. You say it's "failing because there's a lot of files". That's not normal. That's the problem you should be trying to solve. Can you update your question with more details about that failure? That said, the reason the activities you've taken is because those changes are still in your commit history. There are ways to rewrite your commit history to solve that, but I'd recommend focusing on fixing the issue you're having with pushing.

@DanielMann added more info. Maybe the error is pointing to some other issue. However the size of the delta(over 400MB) makes me suspect that its the large size of total files being pushed that maybe the issue.

If you actually want these files to be version controlled, use Git LFS, which is designed to store large files. If you don't want these files in your repository at all, look at Git filter-branch or tools like BFG to purge them from your repo's history; it will be as if they were never put in the repo at all. Once you commit a file, the file is in the repo. If you remove it in a later commit, it's still there in the old commit. Thus, if you want the file totally purged from the repo as though it were never there, you have to use something that walks back through all of the prior commits.

.gitignore doesn't remove the tracked files from tracking. See the doc. You need to purge those commits. It's probably easier to start a new repo, unless the history of the current repo is important.

It could be slow because the commits with a lot of files are still being tracked in your commit history. You will have to remove them from the history, which can be a little risky if you haven't done it before. One thing you could try is just to create a new repository, and just push your code on this new repo, and see if that makes things faster. If it does, and you need the commit history, you can look into editing the commit history.

Is that "could" or "is"? Because that makes the difference between a comment and an answer. Remember, you can always [edit] and improve your answer.
